# Shrink Wrap odd distortion

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

[image][image]

[image: With curve mod]

When using the shrink wrap modifier it seems to be squashing the mesh as it goes round the corner of the object I'm trying to fit it to. Is there any way to deform the mesh evenly without this 'squashing'?

Thanks

Ross

Comment: Target shape is quite simple, maybe you should use Curve modifer rather than Shrinkwrap?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Would I have to draw a curve to conform to?

Comment: Curve can be created from target's single loopcut, ALT-C for conversion from mesh

Comment: Sorry to ask again but how do I cut the object to appear in the right position. The curve mod just seems the shape in random ways. I've tried all axis. See new pic in original post

Comment: Just tweak object location of a mesh. For rotation you can also adjust its rotation or curve's tilt option. If you are still struggling, please share a file

Comment: I've set the origins of the curve and the mesh so the are the same but the mesh is appearing offset. It should be centred and wrapping around the curve. Apologies for the wetransfer. Blend Exchange doesn't appear to be working today. https://we.tl/t-i4ke02tfxF

Comment: I parented both curve and mesh to an empty, cleared their location and moved mesh a bit on X axis, also set X rotation to -90. http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51920

Comment: Thankyou Sir! You've help me a lot! Have a great day.

Comment: Why do you need a new surface? If all you are doing is putting a label, don't use a mesh. Instead, create the label as part of the material ( Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447). Adding a mesh very closely on top of another might turn into Z-fighting errors.

Answer (score 1):

.. But why not just make some temporary edges in your tin, and make your label by duplicating some faces and separating to a new object? It <kbd>U</kbd>unwraps cleanly, if you keep the aspect ratio, and can be scaled to your image?

[image]